# Invoke python application from lambda written in go

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers, aws-lambda-go

I'm developing an aws based application entirely in golang though I have a piece of python code I need to invoke in a lambda function as a separate subprocess.

The python code is written as a CLI application and it's hard to make a lambda out of it, so I'd like to run it as a subprocess in my golang based lambda function.

Is there any way to do that? As far as I know I can create a layer, but how can I install python to the layer?